# Clarification on activity launch mode :"single task"

Tags: android

The android documentation defines single task launch mode as :-

> The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the
>   root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the
>   existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather
>   than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can
>   exist at a time

Now my question is what happens in the case where the instance of activity already exists in a separate task but it is not at the top of the task. Are all activities above this activity destroyed and the new intent is delivered to this activity ? (as in `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`  with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`)

Comment: Here is visual guide https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will. You can test it by making a simple test app. New intent will be received in `onNewIntent()`